# Not getting any result back when using useDispatch and useSelector with async actions React-Redux hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been learning how to use Redux recently and decided to refactor one of my classes to a functional component with hooks. However, I don't get any result back when I dispatch the action.

Products Component:

```
const Products = () =>   {

  const products = useSelector(state => state.products)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type:"FETCH_PRODUCTS", payload: products});
  })


    return (
      <Container>
        <Top>
          <StyledNavLink to="/products/add">Add Product </StyledNavLink>
        </Top>
        <ProductList products={products} />
      </Container>
    );
  }

export default Products;
```

Action:

```
export const fetchProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {

  try {
    const response = await api.get("/products");

    dispatch({type: "FETCH_PRODUCTS", payload: response.data})
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
```

Reducer:

```
const productReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_PRODUCT":
      return state

    case "FETCH_PRODUCTS":
      return action.payload

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Root Reducer:

```
import productReducer from "./productReducer";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products: productReducer
});
```

Index:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

The code returns values when i use class components.

Comment: you need to use action like this

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  })